# Changing PYTHONHOME causes ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, centos, mod-wsgi, fabric, importerror

I am trying to deploy a Flask web app via mod_wsgi on Apache. I cannot use the default Python environment because it was compiled with UCS-2 Unicode instead of UCS-4, and I cannot recompile it for this one case. Thus, a virtual environment. Virtual environments would have been used anyway, but that error means that I can't get away with using the default Python install and just adding the virtual environment's modules to the `PYTHONPATH`, which otherwise would have let me avoid the current problem entirely by accident.

I found the [documentation for `mod_wsgi` to change which Python executable to use](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIPythonHome.html). However, when attempting to do so, the server fails to work properly. `/var/log/httpd/error_log` rapidly floods with the line `ImportError: No module named site`.

I have checked every similar question I can find here and elsewhere, and not yet had success. Experimentation has shown that as far as I can tell, the problem occurs when changing PYTHONHOME without activating a virtual environment - and the way the automated deployment works (via Fabric), as far as I can tell I can't activate a virtual environment.

---

### Apache config

My current `httpd.conf` for the app:

```
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/dir/containing/wsgi/file/and/app:/path/to/virtualenv/lib:/path/to/virtualenv/lib/site-packages

WSGIPythonHome /path/to/virtualenv

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

User user

Group group

<VirtualHost *>

    ServerName servername.generic.com

    DocumentRoot /path/to/dir/containing/wsgi/file/and/app/static_dev/

    WSGIDaemonProcess appname user=user group=group threads=2

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/dir/containing/wsgi/file/and/app/app.wsgi

    <Directory /path/to/dir/containing/wsgi/file/and/app>
        WSGIProcessGroup appname
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### Data I've found from failed attempts

I know that the error is not in my `app.wsgi`, because when I added the line `raise Exception('tried to open the file')` at the very top to check that, the existing `ImportError` kept happening instead of that new `Exception`.

I have confirmed via `ldd` that my version of `mod_wsgi` is for Python 2.7.

I have tried setting `WSGIPythonHome /path/to/virtualenv/bin/` and `WSGIPythonHome /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python`, with the same result as the current state.

I have tried omitting the `WSGIPythonHome` directive, in which case it loads the `app.wsgi` as it should, but breaks on a later import as described at the top (the reason I can't just do that).

I have tried omitting the `WSGIPythonPath` directive and leaving it up to `app.wsgi` to add things to the PYTHONPATH, with the same result as the current state.

I have tried putting the path-setting as an argument to `WSGIDaemonProcess` instead of as the `WSGIPythonPath` directive, with the same result as the current state.

I have confirmed that there is a `site.py` in `/path/to/virtualenv/lib`.

I have confirmed that no other non-app-specific Apache `.conf` files being used (default settings, automatic module loads, etc) contain the string "WSGI", so I don't think there's any conflicts here.

If I activate the virtual environment from the command line I can import `site` without an error, just for the sake of testing that it does in fact exist in the environment. However, this is insufficient because it needs to start smoothly from a single call to `sudo systemctl start httpd.service` due to the deployment tools in use, and that seems to not care about the venv of the current shell session.

If, from a default state, I `export PYTHONHOME=/path/to/virtualenv`, attempting to open the Python REPL exits immediately with `ImportError: No module named site`.

If I activate the virtual environment and then set `PYTHONHOME`, I get the same import error.

If I activate the virtual environment and don't touch `PYTHONHOME`, `echo $PYTHONHOME` outputs a blank line, and the Python REPL works fine. In the Python REPL while in the virtualenv:

```
(virtualenv)-bash-4.2$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 14 2014, 13:26:38)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/path/to/virtualenv'
>>> sys.exec_prefix
'/path/to/virtualenv'
```

Even though setting `PYTHONHOME` to the same value didn't work.

If I try `export PYTHONHOME=:/path/to/virtualenv` or `export PYTHONHOME=/path/to/virtualenv:`, explicitly setting only one of `prefix` and `exec_prefix`, it fails with the same import error in either case.

If I activate the virtual environment and set `PYTHONHOME` in one of those latter two ways, the unset one appears to default to `/` rather than to the usual default value, but the Python REPL runs fine:

```
# Setting only exec_prefix
(virtualenv)-bash-4.2$ export PYTHONHOME=:/path/to/virtualenv
(virtualenv)-bash-4.2$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 14 2014, 13:26:38)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/'
>>> sys.exec_prefix
'/path/to/virtualenv'
>>> quit()
# Setting only prefix
(.virtualenv)-bash-4.2$ export PYTHONHOME=/path/to/virtualenv:
(.virtualenv)-bash-4.2$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 14 2014, 13:26:38)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/path/to/virtualenv'
>>> sys.exec_prefix
'/'
```

Unfortunately, since the deployment script doesn't care what environment is activated, that doesn't solve it. Trying to set `WSGIPythonHome` in such a fashion makes no difference whatsoever.

I have noticed one further thing: The Python in the virtualenv is **2.7.8**. The Python run outside the virtualenv (`usr/bin/python`) is **2.7.5**. I do not know - would this affect the setting of `PYTHONHOME` somehow? I would hope not - since that seems to defeat the entire purpose of using `WSGIPythonHome` to run a virtualenv as compared to just setting `sys.path` inside the `app.wsgi` file, the ability to start from a different executable - but I cannot rule it out, clueless as I am.

The 2.7.8 Python in `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python` has a `sys.real_prefix` of `/network-mounted-drive/sw/python/python-2.7.8`.

I changed the deployment to build from `/network-mounted-drive/sw/python/python-2.7.5`, then did more tests. Results as follows:

Attempting to start httpd gives the same import error as before.

Setting PYTHONHOME to the location of the virtual environment, then running python:

```
-bash-4.2$ echo $PYTHONHOME
/path/to/virtualenv
-bash-4.2$ python
ImportError: No module named site
```

Setting PYTHONHOME to the location of the virtual environment, then explicitly running the virtual environment's python binary (activating the virtual environment and then running `python` gives the same result):

```
# In the directory just above the virtualenv
-bash-4.2$ ./virtualenv/bin/python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar 14 2016, 14:13:09)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/path/to/virtualenv'
>>> sys.exec_prefix
'/path/to/virtualenv'
>>> sys.real_prefix
'/network-mounted-drive/sw/python/python-2.7.5
```

---

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble following the setup.  Have you installed a parallel installation of Python 2.7 on this system?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes, the virtual environment at `/path/to/virtualenv` includes a parallel install of Python 2.7 compiled with the appropriate Unicode representation, as `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/{python,python2,python2.7}`.

Comment: @dhowland oops, forgot to ping you with prev. comment.

Comment: How can the virtual environment include a parallel install? Virtual environments need to chain off a separate install. Where is the original Python 2.7.8 installed? What is ``sys.prefix`` for the Python 2.7.8 without virtual environment activated? You can't just copy a virtual environment from a separate system if that is what you have done. Nor can you just copy in a ``python`` binary into a virtual environment from elsewhere. How did you create the virtual environment?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I will have to ask about that when I get back into work Monday - I'm not the person who configures the VMs. The virtual environment was made from the Python binary on a clean virtual environment that was on the VM when it was passed off to me. I don't know where they chained that one off from. Again, though, it does seem to work fine if activated as long as I don't change PYTHONHOME manually.

Comment: When you run ``python`` from virtual environment, what do you get for ``sys.real_prefix``. This should be the Python version it is chained off. If it is in ``/usr/local`` or other non standard directory, the problem is going to be that mod_wsgi likely was not compiled to pick up shared library for Python from the proper location and picking up system Python still instead, causing problems. This problem can arise when have multiple Python X.Y with different patch level, on same system in different places.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton My prior comment was inaccurate due to false recollection - the virtual environment was made from a Python install on an always-mounted network drive. The virtual environment's `sys.real_prefix` points to that. The virtual environment that came on the VM (unused) has a `sys.real_prefix` of a 2.7.10 install on the same network drive. There is a 2.7.5 install on that drive as well - I'll try redeploying with that, and see what I get.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Okay, building the virtual environment off of the networked 2.7.5 did not solve the problem. However, it did change the results of some of the tests - I have edited those differences in.

Comment: I am unable to test building the virtual environment off of the local python install at `/usr/bin` - trying that leads to deployment issues due to the fact that the local install of python does not have either pip or virtualenv installed. I don't have the required permissions to add them.

Comment: When you have multiple versions of Python for same X.Y in different locations, when building mod_wsgi and installing it, you need to set the environment variable ``LD_RUN_PATH`` to the library directory where the Python shared library is installed for the version you want to use. Otherwise it will pick up the system X.Y Python shared library instead and you will have issues. Don't need to set this when later running Apache, only during the build.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Got it. If I could set that automatically in deployment it would be great - the system is unfortunately rather rigid (parameters being "load X code to Y machine/directory, chaining the venv off of Z Python install"). Solution was found, below. Good to know in future, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution found: The issue seems to have been in trying to use a virtual environment built from something other than the local python install on the system.

Solved by pushing the problem of "local python install on the deployment VM doesn't have pip installed" up the chain to someone with the permissions required to install pip, since no attempted workarounds via networked python installs worked.

The issue of actually using a virtual environment chained from a Python install on a network drive for mod_wsgi may be insoluble, or at least I couldn't figure it out in a reasonable amount of time relative to the bureaucratic solution.